# Rails PostgreSQL numeric field overflow ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have a decimal field for price on my schema and every time that i try to insert the price the pg comes with this ERROR. anybody could give me any light? thank's

**configuration**

```
t.decimal  "price",  :precision => 2, :scale => 2
```

**ERROR**

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 2, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 1.
: INSERT INTO "items" ("category_id", "name", "price", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14) RETURNING "id"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I quote the manual on [Arbitrary Precision Numbers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL):

> The scale of a numeric is the count of decimal digits in the
>   fractional part, to the right of the decimal point. The precision of a
>   numeric is the total count of significant digits in the whole number,
>   that is, the number of digits to both sides of the decimal point.

You cannot assign numbers `>= 1` to a column of the data type `numeric(2,2)`. There is just no room for digits before the decimal point.

`0.999` and `0.995` are in violation of the type as well, as they round to `1` with a given *scale* of *2*.