# "PG::Error - numeric field overflow" on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have built an app that queries Google Analytics for the last 7 days of data. Everything works locally. On Heroku, the process runs smoothly until it tries to get data for today's date. I then get the following error:

```
2012-10-29T02:32:02+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:   numeric field overflow
2012-10-29T02:32:02+00:00 app[web.1]: DETAIL:  A field with precision 8, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^6.
```

I have tried to figure out which variable it's not happy with but I don't know right now. I am assuming it's something related to date or time.

Any thoughts or ideas would be great :)

-- update ---

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20121014153338) do
  create_table "analytics", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "site"
    t.integer  "visits"
    t.date     "start_date"
    t.date     "end_date"
    t.decimal  "revenue_per_transaction", :precision => 8, :scale => 2
    t.integer  "transactions"
    t.decimal  "item_quantity",           :precision => 8, :scale => 2
    t.integer  "goal_starts"
    t.integer  "goal_completes"
    t.decimal  "goal_conversion",         :precision => 8, :scale => 2
    t.datetime "created_at",                                            :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                            :null => false
    t.decimal  "goal_abandon",            :precision => 8, :scale => 2
    t.decimal  "revenue",                 :precision => 8, :scale => 2
    t.string   "source"
  end

end
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D%20numeric%20field%20overflow and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10609964/398670

Answer (score 7):

You have a `numeric` field with typmod `numeric(8,2)` and you're trying to store a value greater than `999999.99` in it. See [the PostgreSQL manual on `NUMERIC`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) for information on numeric scale and precision, which are the qualifiers shown after the type in parentheses.

[This earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10609855/398670) appears to cover the same issue with Rails, showing the Rails model and how the scale and precision are assigned.

`NUMERIC` isn't a date/time field, it's a number field.

Demo of the issue:

```
regress=> SELECT  NUMERIC(8,2) '999999.99';
  numeric  
-----------
 999999.99
(1 row)

regress=> SELECT  NUMERIC(8,2) '1000000.00';
ERROR:  numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 8, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^6.
```

It's a pity that Pg doesn't tell you what field this is when it is a field. It's difficult for it to do so, though, because it doesn't usually know which value is going to go into which field when it's parsing string literals. Enable `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf`, `ALTER USER ... SET`, `ALTER DATABASE ... SET`, or per-session with `SET log_statement = 'all'` then re-test and examine the query logs.

Also look at the table definitions with `\dt` in `psql` to see what might have the type `numeric(8,2)` and could be causing the problem.

As for why it works locally: Is the local DB PostgreSQL? Some Rails users seem to have a very odd setup where they use SQLite locally, and PostgreSQL on Heroku. This is a recipe for chaos and deployment problems. Use the same database in development and testing. If it *is* PostgreSQL locally, is it the same version?

Comment: Thanks for your help! So this could actually be total hits to the site. What migration would I want to run to allow PG to accommodate that number?

Comment: @RichardBurton Hard to say since you haven't shown your original schema definitions / rails model. I'm not much good with the Ruby/Rails side anyway; I'd use Rails' `execute` in the migration to run the raw SQL `ALTER TABLE whatever_table ALTER COLUMN the_problem_column TYPE NUMERIC`, making it an unbounded `numeric`. There might be some properly Rails-y way I don't know.

Comment: @RichardBurton Added some links

Comment: Thanks a lot -- I just added the schema so I guess it's one of those three variables with `:precision => 8, :scale => 2`

Comment: @RichardBurton Yup, that seems highly likely. I'd enable query logging to see for sure. There's no real benefit to setting a restrictive numeric scale or precision, so unless you need to constrain the scale and precision for data integrity / business rule reasons you can leave them unconstrained or use a big limit. Setting a small scale does not save storage space except in that it prevents you from storing bigger numerics.

Comment: Awesome -- what's the migration to adjust that? I have googled around but I am not 100% sure yet. Will enable logging thanks!

Comment: @RichardBurton As I said, I'm not much into the Rails side, so I'm not sure how/if data type change migrations work. I'd recommend asking a new `ruby-on-rails` tagged question for that and link back to this one for context.

Comment: For anyone reading this later, the follow-up is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13115772/398670