# How do I create a rails migration to remove/change precision and scale on decimal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am trying to remove the precision and scale attributes from decimal (PostgreSQL `NUMERIC`) fields in my database?

The fields:

```
t.decimal  "revenue_per_transaction", :precision => 8, :scale => 2
t.decimal  "item_quantity",           :precision => 8, :scale => 2
t.decimal  "goal_conversion",         :precision => 8, :scale => 2
t.decimal  "goal_abandon",            :precision => 8, :scale => 2
t.decimal  "revenue",                 :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

What do I need to add to my migration to change these to unbounded scale and precision, or to increase the scale? At the moment I'm hitting the scale limit and getting errors like:

```
ERROR:   numeric field overflow
```

Here's the context: ["PG::Error - numeric field overflow" on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115229/pgerror-numeric-field-overflow-on-heroku/13115261)

Comment: Essentially, looking for the rails-migration way of writing `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... TYPE NUMERIC`.

Comment: accept answer or add comment on why it was not accepted?

Answer (score 84):

format :

```
change_column(table_name, column_name, type, options): Changes the column to a different type using the same parameters as add_column.
```

First in you terminal:

```
rails g migration change_numeric_field_in_my_table
```

Then in your migration file:

```
class ChangeNumbericFieldInMyTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
   change_column :my_table, :revenue_per_transaction, :decimal, :precision => give whatever, :scale => give whatever
  end
end
```

then

```
run rake db:migrate
```

Source : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

Comment: how about removing precision?

Comment: @Hamdan you would need to set the precision/scale to the default values, which differ depending on your database: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column

Comment: There is no default for Postgres though:
`PostgreSQL: :precision [1..infinity], :scale [0..infinity]. No default.`

But not specifying precision and scale in `change_column` seems to work.

Answer (score -4):

In your migration file change your field to :integer
and run
run rake db:migrate

Comment: You need a new migration file. Using the same migration file will not work.

Comment: This will decrease the scale to 0